# differential equation of a function depending on the hypergeometric series $F(a,b;c;z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function, differential, hypergeometric-function

Show that
$$y(z) = z^{1-c} F(a+1-c, b+1-c, 2-c, z)$$
satisfies the differential equation $$z(1-z)\frac{d^{2}y}{dz^{2}} + (c-(a+b+1)z)\frac{dy}{dz} - aby = 0.$$

I know that:
$F(a,b,c,z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{n}(b)_{n}}{n!(c)_{n}} z^{n}$
$(a)_{n} = a(a+1) \dots (a+n-1)$ if $n \geq 1$ and $1$ if $n=0$
$(a)_{n} = \frac{\Gamma{(a+n)}}{\Gamma{(a)}}$ and $\Gamma{(n+1)} = n!$

I think I should somehow rewrite $F(a+1-c, b+1-c, 2-c, z)$ with the things I know and then differentiate $y$ twice to $z$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use any facts about the hypergeometric function to prove this? Or must you work directly from the series expansion?

Comment: Yess, I think that's the intention (to use facts about the hypergeometic function).